# $\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z^3}dz$ - Cauchy formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Compute the integral $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z^3}dz,$$ where
>   $f(z)=az^3+bz^2+cz+d$ and $\gamma : [0, 4 \pi] \to \mathbb{C}$,
>   $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$.

So by the Cauchy formula $\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(z)}{z^3}dz= \frac{f^{(2)}(0)2 \pi i}{2!}=2\pi b i$, but the real answer is $4\pi b i$. How could we consider the interval $[0, 4 \pi]$ to obtain the good answer?

Answer (score 1):

Since the curve wraps around twice, you forgot to multiply by 2. In general, you multiply by the winding number of the curve you do the integral around.

A quick and dirty way to see this for your simple curve is to just partition the curve tracing out the circle twice into two curves, each tracing the circle once. Call these $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$. Then

$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z^3} dz = \int_{\gamma_1+\gamma_2} \frac{f(z)}{z^3}dz =\int_{\gamma_1} \frac{f(z)}{z^3}dz + \int_{\gamma_2} \frac{f(z)}{z^3}dz $$

by linearity of the integral.

The general proof doesn't work quite like this because curves can be quite complicated. For a proof of the general case, you could check out Conway's text "Functions of One Complex Variable". The case involving the general curve of arbitrary winding number is  Theorem 4.5.4.

Comment: I understand, but could you explain rigourously?

Comment: @Dr.Dray See if this helps.